# Replace value in one column with another

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery, powerpivot, powerbi-desktop

I have some doubts, i want to replace the values in column for the values of the other one, i have my query like this
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns1", each ["Alcance-Canal"], null , Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"CANAL/ES"})

however it still doesn't work, could you please assist me?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is add a custom column with formula

```
= if [columnname] = "something" then [columnname] else [othercolumnname]
```

or

```
= if [columnname] = "something" then "anotherthing" else [othercolumnname]
```